# find password protected pdf from a folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, pdf, cmd, errorlevel

I tried to make a batch file to list password protected pdf files from a folder, I've more than 10000 files in that folder and the protected files are only around 40.
Please see my code below:

```
@echo off
cls
z:
cd\
for %%X in (*.pdf) do (
    type "%%X" | find "Encrypt" >NUL
    if errorlevel 0 echo %%X >> D:\pradeesh.txt)
exit
```

in this I am getting all the pdf files in that folder, when I change the error level to 1 I am getting all the files without password. I simply want the opposite result, can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1):

You could just change your errorlevel line to:

```bat
    If Not ErrorLevel 1 (Echo %%X)>>D:\pradeesh.txt)
```

Alternatively you may be able to see if `FindStr` reads those files and just use:

```bat
FindStr/M "Encrypt" Z:\*.pdf>D:\pradeesh.txt
```